# Create nestled JSON (python)

Tags: json, python-3.x

The code below takes data that I have extracted from various websites and writes the data to a JSON file.  I would like to create a nestled section called {nlp_description} for the NLP items (Unigrams,Bigrams,Trigrams).

How do I accomplish this task?

```
json_data = {}
json_data['news_sites'] = []

json_data['news_sites'].append({
        'URL': website_href,
        'Title': website_title,
        'Snippet': website_snippet,
        'Description': website_description,
        'Unigrams': unigrams,
        'Bigrams': bigrams,
        'Trigrams': trigrams})

    with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(json_data, outfile, ensure_ascii=False,indent=6)
```

I tried doing this, but it failed:

```
json_data['news_sites'].append({
        'URL': website_href,
        'Title': website_title,
        'Snippet': website_snippet,
        'Description': website_description,
        'nlp_description':
            ('Unigrams': unigrams,
             'Bigrams': bigrams,
             'Trigrams': trigrams)})

    with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(json_data, outfile, ensure_ascii=False,indent=6)
```

Comment: Do you mean simply `..., 'nlp_description': (unigrams, bigrams, trigarms)})`?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nlp_description` key is represented as a wrong tuple. Maybe what you're looking for is this:

```
json_data['news_sites'].append({
    'URL': website_href,
    'Title': website_title,
    'Snippet': website_snippet,
    'Description': website_description,
    'nlp_description':(
        {
            'Unigrams': unigrams,
            'Bigrams': bigrams,
            'Trigrams': trigrams
        }
    )
})
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed!  I normally write data to a CSV file or to a database, so this is my first time writing to a JSON file. THANKS.